# List of questions doesn't update when selecting a custom tab

Tags: bug, new-nav

I have a custom tab with two tags on it, [infragistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/infragistics) and [ignite-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ignite-ui). 
When I go to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) it automatically goes to the home tab, like this:

[image]

Which is ok, but I never really look at the home tab. I usually go right to the tab I set up.

**But when I click on my custom tab with the two tags, the question list doesn't update.**

[image: Stack Overflow ERROR]

However the URL does change.

**Additional Info:**

- Refreshing the page, when on that tab, does update the question list.
- This is only happening for this particular tab. I have other tabs that have multiple tags on them and they work fine.
- This also happens when switching to this tab from any other tab

### Update 4/15/2016

This is now working correctly and is no longer happening.